# double (3,3) > sending 1.3 > stored 0.999

Tags: mysql

It is knocking my socks off...
MySQL DB

weight is defined as `double (3,3)`

```
INSERT INTO xxx (`weight`) VALUES ( 1.3)
```

why does the DB store `0.999`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(3,3)` indicates a total length of 3 digits, with 3 decimal places.  Perhaps you want `(6,3)`.

See the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) for details.

Answer (score 4):

This wouldn't work on a MySQL 8.0 installation, because of the following error:

### Input

```
insert into xxx(weight) value (1,3)
```

#### error

```
Out of range value for column 'weight' at row 1
```

<sub>See: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3870051cbe7c2a80679ed584eb33ed3) for the example</sub>

In your case, you must be using an older version of MySQL which will store the maximum allowed value which is `0.999`.

## Fix

If you create a table with `double(4,3)` or  `double(6,3)` as pointed out in the accepted answer, then it should work.

#### Table Definition

```
create table xxx (weight double (4,3))
```

#### Insert Statement

```
insert into xxx (weight) value (1.3)
```

#### Select

```
select * from xxx
```

> ```
> | weight |
> | -----: |
> |  1.300 |
> ```

<sub>See: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86375049de734aa9a40769900c4d18fd) for an example</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Do not ever use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  It leads to an extra 'rounding', and can lead unnecessary/unwanted truncation (which is what you got.)